# Inject ViewModel into compose code by Koin in Compose Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, koin, compose-multiplatform

Is there any way to inject the ViewModel into `composable` function of **Compose Multiplatform**?

I have tried with Koin dependency injection but it seems not yet ready to inject ViewModel in common module yet.
Is there any alternative way or library that can be used in Compose Multiplatform project?

Comment: What viewmodel library are you using?

Comment: I wasn't using any VM library till now, was using my own implementation. But thinking about shifting to Moko VM library.

Comment: I have been using Moko VM library alongside Koin and although it needs more changes I've managed to get it to work nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently proceeding with manual dependency injection for my use case. But Koin seems working on ways to injecting instances into composable functions. By using, under development function, koinInject() of Koin library, it seems possible to get instances injected.
Details can be found [here](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-compose/multiplatform/)

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to try this?

```
val viewModel = remember { AnyVieweModel() }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this doesn't answer my question. I asked for a way to Inject viewModel instance into Composable function as like we do in android now using hilt. Your solution indicates instantiating viewModel which is not the right one in this scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using koin-compose library

First, add this commonMain

```
commonMain.dependencies {
//...
implementation("io.insert-koin:koin-compose:1.1.2")
}
```

Now you can inject it through the parameter

```
fun LoginScreen(viewModel: LoginViewModel = koinInject()) {

}
```

---

Keep in mind to configure the ViewModel injection by koin in correct way for android, Ios and JVM:

### **commonMain**

**CommonModule**

```
expect class PlatformModule {
    val module: Module
}

val commonModule = module {
    includes(userModule, loginModule)
}
```

---

### **androidMain**

**MyApp**

```
class MyApp : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
            androidLogger(if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Level.ERROR else Level.NONE)
            androidContext(this@MyApp)
            modules(PlatformModule().module + commonModule)
        }
    }
}
```

**CommonModule**:

```
 actual class PlatformModule {
    actual val module: Module = module {
        viewModel {
            LoginViewModel(get())
        }
    }
}
```

---

### desktopMain

**CommonModule**:

```
actual class PlatformModule {
    actual val module: Module = module {

        factory { LoginViewModel(get()) }
    }
}
```

**MainKT**

```
fun main() = application {

    startKoin {
        modules(PlatformModule().module + commonModule)
    }
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication, title = "Movies-KMP") {
        App()
    }
}
```